# Can i repair windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop thats ~7-8 years old. It has windows 7 on it. Overall it works fine and i can do most of the things i want to do, but the issue is that apps start up slowly. Even if the app is very small it takes quite a while to start up.

I know that you should reinstall windows occationally to fix the accumulated issues. But can i just run some sort of repair tool that can fix the issued without having to reinstall the windows?

Comment: Unlikely. And Windows 7 is about to become unsupported. Do not invest time or money in an obsolete OS.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Well i dislike windows 8 and 10... so im not gona upgrade either. Not even sure my laptop can handle 8 or 10

Comment: It most likely can handle a very modern Linux distro like Ubuntu or one of its lighter variants. OSes that don't have security updates shouldn't be used if connected to the internet, it's dangerous for you and others.

Comment: "I know that you should reinstall windows occationally to fix the accumulated issues." - I had the same Windows installation for 7 years.  The Windows 7 installation was upgraded to Windows 8, then upgrade to Windows 8.1, then Windows 8.1 Update, then Windows 10 1507, Windows 10 1511, Windows 10 1607, Windows 10 1703.  The only reason I stop using that installation was due to a HDD failure.  It is a myth, that Windows will "slow" down, the only thing that slows Windows down are buggy applications.  Registry Cleaners are snake oil, the registry, was designed to have invalid enteries.

Comment: First check the SMART data for the hard disk, if it is not too old to support that.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that you should reinstall windows occasionally to fix the accumulated issues

Honestly, this is a myth.
*Sure, this should be marked* <sup>[citation required]</sup> *but in 20 years of running & supervising Windows machines I have never known it to be actually necessary.*

So, yes - you can run 'some sort' of repair tool.

Software recommendations, however, are off-topic for Super User, so *which* repair tool you could ask about on our sister site, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

However, before chasing the 'holy grail' of a fast yet old machine, consider that compared to a new machine with more RAM & an SSD drive, it is always going to feel slow.

Comment: Im just tyring to get it back up to speed. Some weird behaviour is happening with my laptop. Basically when i start an application i can open task manager and see how it slowly accumulates memory before opening. Like when i open a broswer, in taskmanager the memory usage slowy increases: 300, 600, 1000, .... until it reaches like 100 000 or something then it finally opens, about 30-60 second after clicking.

Comment: Try this [freeware version is sufficient] https://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html Do everything it says, precisely as it says. Don't skip **anything**, don't shortcut. Prepare to spend at least half a day doing this, perhaps even a full day. Some of what it does is proprietary, some is what a fully-qualified Microsoft IT guy would do by hand using Windows' built-in tools - you just don't need to have that knowledge.

Comment: Il try it when i can allocate a full day on this.

Answer (score -2):

All those may be due to accumilated cache, viruses running in background etc etc... But as windows 7 uses aero effects and some visual effects, you can try disabling those (remember that this makes your interface not much beautiful as it used to be)

• search for "Adjust the appearence and performance of windows"

• select  " Adjust for best performance"

If it doesn't fix your problem, you can use some tuneup softwear like AVG pc Tuneup (I highly recommend it : )

If still you got this problem, you can try reinstalling windows 7 ( because your pc may not support windows 10 ). Reinstalling Windows mostly fixes all those problems.

Good Luck for it * )

Comment: I'm afraid this just reinforces all the myths.